# Upgrade BitTorrent Sync

Tags: sync, bittorrent

I just received a notification for BitTorrent Sync 2.0 to upgrade. It takes me to a downloads page on the website, and I pulled down the appropriate package for my architecture (x64), kinda lost as to what I do next.

Some help would rock : )

Answer (score 0):

The way I normally upgrade is more of a manual process:

- Go to https://www.getsync.com/platforms/desktop, click the
  appropriate Linux link. Cancel the download and you should see the
  "Click here if your download didn't already happen." message
- Right-click this link and copy the URL to clipboard or write it down
- On the Linux server, create a temp folder somewhere, and run the
  "***wget*** " command to download the file to temp folder
- From the temp folder, run "***tar xf***" to extract the btsync files
- At this point I normally stop the existing btsync service using the
  "***kill***" command, renamed the existing executable to *btsync_xxx* (where
  *xxx* is the existing version)
- Copy the new executable from temp folder to your current **btsync**
  folder - you now have the previous exec and the new exec
  available
- Run the new exec; if all goes well, you should be able to login via
  web interface with all previous folders and settings in place

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Linux GUI, double-clicking the downloaded file should allow you to extract the btsync executable.

Might be a good idea to stop the app, rename the existing file and then extract the new one to the same folder.